# Changes to component not saved after modifying the content through event handler

Tags: event-system

Here is what I am doing in my method on component save.

- I am getting the component content and fetching all the "a" tags modifying it and replacing it. The content is modified but getting the following error.
- System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save(String filename)

  ```
              XmlDocument doc = component.Content.OwnerDocument;
              string compContent = doc.OuterXml;               
              if (component == null) return;                                      
              List<string> aTags = GetATags(compContent);
              if (aTags.Count.Equals(0)) return;
              //Modify the href attribute value 
              foreach (string aTag in aTags)
              {
                  string refaTag = new string(aTag.ToCharArray());
                  string newAtag = ESUtil.SetHrefTagAttribute("href", refaTag);
                  compContent = compContent.Replace(refaTag, newAtag);
              }
              Logger.WriteWarning("Final doc" +compContent , ErrorCode.GENERAL);
              component.Content.OwnerDocument.Save(compContent);
  ```
- The Final doc has my modified content.

Comment: You shouldn't try saving the component's XML like that, you need to set Component.Content = `XmlElement` - where this would be the root element of a XmlDocument like your doc.

Comment: I tried something like this. doc.Save(compContent);
                    component.Content = doc.OwnerDocument.DocumentElement;
                    component.Save(); . What wrong am I doing here?

Comment: I would expect that to work - except for component.Save() which is not needed - this will actually trigger the event to happen again and may go into a loop - don't call component.Save() in an Initiated phase, Tridion will do the save for you.

Comment: I agree component.save() is not required.Removed it.But I get the same error. "System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save(String filename)"

Comment: Don't call doc.Save then - try doc.LoadXml(compContent)

Comment: Just replace the last line with: component.Content.LoadXml(compContent);

Comment: @NunoLinhares : doc.LoadXml(compContent) works just fine. Thank you.

Comment: doc.LoadXml(compContent);
                    if(doc.DocumentElement != null) component.Content = doc.DocumentElement;  //doc.OwnerDocument.Document is not needed. I was getting object null reference exception.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is trying to save XML into the file with path equal to your XML. 
What you need to do is set the value of `component.Content` property. After, depending on your event system implementetion you need to either call `component.Save()`, or do nothing.

If you have subscribed to `Component` `SaveEventArgs` in inititated state and this is your component - do nothing, otherwise call `Save()`

Comment: Yes, I have subscribed to Component SaveEventArgs EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, SaveEventArgs>(MyMethod, EventPhases.Initiated);.

Comment: I have not tried what you mentioned.component.Content.LoadXml(compContent). I am guessing even that should work.Thank you.